# How to change default "please include an @ in the email address"?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, forms, bootstrap-4

I've been able to change the error message when the user has not typed their email in yet, but how do I change the error message when the user types in their email with the wrong format?

This is my code written in Bootstrap 4 style:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" required="" class="form-control" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please Enter valid email')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi use this one https://jqueryvalidation.org

Comment: Jquery validation has benefits and flaws. It is worth to study the case.

Comment: @RizkiDPrast is there something simpler?

Comment: @statosdotcom that's true.

Answer (score 3):

You simply can fix this with adding title to input tag

```html
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="freeform_email"
                        placeholder="Enter an email" required="required"
                        oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Enter an email that contains &quot@&quot. Example: info@roshni.nl')" title="Email: the email contains '@'. Example: info@ros-bv.nl" />
```

Yours should be then:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" required="" class="form-control" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please Enter valid email')"  oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" title='<your text>'">
</div>
```

**You're welcome.**

Answer (score 1):

Here’s an example of how to do it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="myForm" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
Email: <input type="text" name="email">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

You’ll have to change the text inside `alert` to include your custom message and `action_page.php` to include your own and add your desired styles all over!

**UPDATE**

If you don't want to implement your own JavaScript functions then you can just go ahead and add conditions to the `oninvalid` as follows:

```
<input type="email" name="email" required="" class="form-control" oninvalid="if (this.value == ''){this.setCustomValidity('This field is required!')} if (this.value != ''){this.setCustomValidity('The email you entered is invalid!')}" oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
```

Comment: Sorry. This code is correct, but it does not answer my question.

Comment: @Anonymous Thank you for your feedback, please check my updated answer.